# Im looking a test plan template document for agile environment. Appreciate if you can share

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, agile

Im preparing some QA template for QA department. We are following Agile development process and im looking a test plan template that can use in agile environment

Comment: Agile is a methodology that dictates the process rather than focussing on the tools/techniques used. You can pick a lot of good test plan templates online. It doesn't matter.

Comment: There is no **A**gile methodology.  There are systems, frameworks, and methodologies that support the philosophy expressed in the [Manifesto for Agile Software Development](https://agilemanifesto.org) via four values and twelve principles.

Answer (score 4):

Whilst it is true that you probably don't need a test plan with agile it is also true that having some sort of strategy helps keep you focused on quality goals and working effectively within your limitations.

The one page test plan is a good summary of the many different approaches to making a test plan that works with agile processes.

https://dojo.ministryoftesting.com/lessons/the-one-page-test-plan

Answer (score -1):

old good IEEE 829. It does not have to be a book, you know. 
another thing what I like - mindmap! Create a mindmap with features you want to test and how. Pin in on the wall in team room. Everyone can cross the feature after it is tested and voila! you have a visual tool of progress and whole team is involved in process and feels responsible for quality.